# Azure storage table REST Api call - Invalid Header

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to invoke the REST API to view the content of Azure Storage table.
Hope I have properly formed Authorization header value and I am getting below error. Please correct me where I am missing in below request (From REST Client app).

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "transformRequest": [
    null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
    null
  ],
  "url": "https://#####.table.core.windows.net/testDB",
  "headers": {
    "x-ms-date": "Thu, 28 Jun 2018 08:39:05 GMT",
    "x-ms-version": "2018-06-28",
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "Authorization": "SharedKeyLite #####:########"
  },
  "data": "",
  "timeout": {}
}
```

And Here is my response Headers:

```
{
  "x-ms-request-id": "3fc23b14-2002-0037-04bc-0e9e56000000",
  "date": "Thu, 28 Jun 2018 08:46:39 GMT",
  "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
  "content-length": "371",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "status": 400
}
```

and Response Body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidHeaderValue</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:3fc23b14-2002-0037-04bc-0e9e56000000
Time:2018-06-28T08:46:40.1148690Z</message>
</error>
```

Here is the JAVA code, I used to generate SignatureString

```
    private void printHash()
    {
//        https://mytestaccount.table.core.windows.net/testDB: this is the url form Azure portal displaying next to table
        String secret = "I Updated my key here";
// Date for string to sign
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
// canonicalizedResource, such as "/testaccount1/Tables"
        String canonicalizedResource = "/testDB";
        String stringToSign = date + "\n" + canonicalizedResource;
        System.out.println(stringToSign);
// HMAC-SHA@%^
        Mac sha256HMAC = null;
        try {
            sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
            sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
            String hash = Base64.encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
            System.out.println(hash);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for computing authorization header? Or are you simply copy the access key from portal and using that in authorization header?

Comment: I have used JAVA code to generate authorization header

Comment: please read the below artilcle i think this solve your query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-sample-create-account

Comment: I think value for your `x-ms-version` request header is incorrect. It should be `2018-03-28` instead of `2018-06-28`.

Comment: I have removed the x-ms-version header, because its optional but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four points to fix:

1. x-ms-version is not optional if you want get content as `application/json;odata=nometadata`. x-ms-version should be set explicitly to `2013-08-15` or later(The latest is [2018-03-28](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/previous-azure-storage-service-versions)) to support this format. See [Json format in table service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/payload-format-for-table-service-operations#json-format-applicationjson-versions-2013-08-15-and-later).
2. Date Format should be `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'`. Two digits to express Day.
3. canonicalizedResource should be `storageAccountName\tableName` like your code remark.
4. To generate SecretKeySpec, `SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(secret), "HmacSHA256");` Because the secret is encoded as Base64.

Comment: Hi Jerry Liu, I appreciate your debug skill, It helped me lot to fix my issue. Still I am fail to get JSON response instead of XML.

Comment: @SaiPrasad Could you offer some details about your error message?

Comment: See my query in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148537/json-format-not-supported-exception-from-azure-storage-rest-api