# JSON format Not supported exception from Azure storage REST API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage

I am working on REST API calls on Azure storage table, I am successful to query table and get response in xml format but when I try to change the Accept header to JSON I am getting the exceptions.

Note: I set the value of x-ms-version to 2018-03-28

```
    headers.put("Authorization", "SharedKey " + store + ":" + hash);
    headers.put("x-ms-date", date);
//        headers.put("x-ms-version","2009-09-19");
    headers.put("x-ms-version","2018-03-28");
    headers.put("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
//        headers.put("Accept","application/atom+xml,application/xml");
    headers.put("Accept","application/json;odata=nometadata");
    headers.put("DataServiceVersion","1.0;NetFx");
    headers.put("MaxDataServiceVersion","1.0;NetFx");
```

I am getting the Response status code 415 with message "`JsonFormatNotSupported`JSON format is not supported."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataServiceVersion` and `MaxDataServiceVersion` are not necessary, but if you want to use, change them to `3.0;NetFx`.

Only 3.0 is compatible with x-ms-version `2013-08-15 or later`. See the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-the-odata-data-service-version-headers).

Comment: Thanks lot @Jerry, we both got solution at same time :)

Answer (score 1):

I have removed below 2 headers and now I am getting the response in JSON format.

```
    headers.put("DataServiceVersion","1.0;NetFx");
    headers.put("MaxDataServiceVersion","1.0;NetFx");
```

Comment: Please remove this answer and accept Jerry Liu's answer.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft Sai posted their answer just 10 seconds apart, thus it is not a duplicate. I don't agree that it should be removed. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20190993)

Comment: I am not removing my solution (I have seen the response after my post) but I accepted @Jerry suggestion.