# Azure storage REST Api call - Invalid Header x-ms-version

Tags: r, azure, azure-storage

Following the advice from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078643/azure-storage-table-rest-api-call-invalid-header), and the API documentation (e.g., [Blob service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api)), I have an `x-ms-version` specified in the header.  My code works against Azurite, and is authenticated by Azure, but returns a

```
HTTP/1.1 400 The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
```

The xml body has more details:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:d39d2cad-301e-009e-1546-3940de000000
Time:2018-08-21T11:58:14.2369850Z</Message>
   <HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName>
   <HeaderValue>2017-01-19</HeaderValue>
</Error>
```

My guess is it is not the format, but the value.  How do I find the right value, or even a list of all possible values that I can try running one at a time, or does someone know that this is a misleading error, and I need to be looking somewhere else?

While playing with this a little more a `x-ms-version=2015-02-21` generates.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is out of range.
```

Here is the request:

```
 -> GET /mike-ecu-test?restype=container&comp=list HTTP/1.1
 -> Host: mikeecutest.blob.core.windows.net
 -> User-Agent: libcurl/7.54.0 r-curl/3.1 httr/1.3.1
 -> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 -> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
 -> Authorization: SharedKey mikeecutest/mike-ecu-test:9j5XodD9OIslzMnzHXiU7c76EpOXFi5jeQITbHk/Y8g=
 -> x-ms-date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 01:35:06 GMT
 -> x-ms-version: 2018-03-28
```

Here is the r code that generates it, credit for the code is answer 4 to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267760/error-connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-api-from-r)

```
library("httr")
azureout <- function(){
    url <- "http://mikeecutest.blob.core.windows.net/mike-ecu-test?restype=container&comp=list"
    sak <- "dfgwhsfhsfg.....hjdkfgs==" 

    requestdate<-format(Sys.time(),"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", tz="GMT")
    msapiversion<- "2018-03-28"
    signaturestring<-paste0("GET",paste(rep("\n",12),collapse=""),
                            "x-ms-date:",requestdate,
                            "x-ms-version:",msapiversion,"\n",
                            "mikeecutest", "\n",
                            "comp:list","\n",
                            "restype:container")

    headerstuff<-add_headers(Authorization=paste0("SharedKey mikeecutest/mike-ecu-test:",
                                                  RCurl::base64(digest::hmac(key=RCurl::base64Decode(sak, mode="raw"),
                                                                             object=enc2utf8(signaturestring),
                                                                             algo= "sha256", raw=TRUE))),
                             `x-ms-date`=requestdate,
                             `x-ms-version`=msapiversion)

    content(GET(url,config = headerstuff, verbose() ))
```

}

Storage API version `2018-03-28` generates a:

```
 <- HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is out of range.
```

Storage API version `2018-02-01` generates a:

```
 <- HTTP/1.1 400 The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
```

Comment: Is the request time in UTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, 2017-01-19 is not a valid Storage service version, see all versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/previous-azure-storage-service-versions). The documentation article [Versioning for the Azure Storage services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services) also suggests the latest API version at the top.

Recommend you to use the latest if there is no specific requirement.

**Update**

See three points to fix:

```
signaturestring<-paste0("GET",paste(rep("\n",12),collapse=""),
                            "x-ms-date:",requestdate,"\n",   # miss "\n"
                            "x-ms-version:",msapiversion,"\n",
                            "/mikeecutest/mike-ecu-test", "\n", # should be /accountname/containername
                            "comp:list","\n",
                            "restype:container")

headerstuff<-add_headers(Authorization=paste0("SharedKey mikeecutest:", # only need accountname here
                                                  RCurl::base64(digest::hmac(key=RCurl::base64Decode(sak, mode="raw"),
                                                                             object=enc2utf8(signaturestring),
                                                                             algo= "sha256", raw=TRUE))),
                             `x-ms-date`=requestdate,
                             `x-ms-version`=msapiversion)
```

Package of REST API is always preferred, you can have a try at that provided by @Hong.

Comment: Thanks, these 4 changes worked.  I'll probably use @Hong's package, that's what I started looking for and was afraid I was going to have to write it.

Comment: Just correcting the version resolve my issue. your 1st line of the text save me.thanks @Jerry

Answer (score 3):

Consider using my [AzureStor](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=AzureRMR) package which is an interface to file and blob storage on Azure. It handles authentication, including both access key and SAS, and admin details like getting the API version right.

```
install.packages("AzureStor")
library(AzureStor)

bl <- blob_endpoint("http://mikeecutest.blob.core.windows.net",
                    key="your_key")

cont <- blob_container(bl, "mike-ecu-test")
list_blobs(cont)
upload_blob(cont, "srcfile", "destblob") # blocked upload is supported for blob storage
download_blob(cont, "srcblob", "destfile")

newcontainer <- create_blob_container(bl, "newcontainer")
delete_blob_container(newcontainer)
```